# How do I get the remaining text after the first occurrence of a word following whitespace?

Tags: java, regex, string

Example:

```
abc     123 xyz
```

Expected result:

```
123 xyz
```

The two strings could be separated by one or more whitespace characters. The text is abritary and there is no guarantee to the number of whitespace and non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

This should give the desired output.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abc     123 xyz";
        String[] result = s.split("\\s+",2);
        System.out.println("Result: "+result[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Be warned that `\s` is broken in Java on U+00A0, `NO-BREAK SPACE`.  This just bit sometbody yesterday here.